# Layout element causing Android Studio 2.3.3 to Completely freeze

Tags: android

In a recent new project, even with a new project, my Android Studio IDE start to freeze unexpectedly when I code. I don't recall doing any updates or anything,  but before I get too paranoid and refresh my PCs, I thought I should ask here first:

I've followed the steps in https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html
The full dump file is too long, but here is a snippet:

```
Attaching to remote server pid, please wait...
2017-09-17 23:08:44
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.112-b06 mixed mode):

"Layoutlib Render Thread" #80 daemon prio=4 os_prio=-1 tid=0x000000001f82c000 nid=0x2d20 runnable [0x0000000032923000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(Throwable.java:783)
    - locked <0x00000000b42caee8> (a java.lang.NumberFormatException)
    at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:265)
    at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:66)
    at java.lang.RuntimeException.<init>(RuntimeException.java:62)
    at java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.<init>(IllegalArgumentException.java:52)
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.<init>(NumberFormatException.java:55)
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDimension(BridgeTypedArray.java:477)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(BridgeTypedArray.java:416)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4178)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:710)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:704)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:700)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor129.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:163)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:222)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at ...
```

the only way out was to terminate the studio.

**Note:** Problem started to happen my two PCs, both running Windows 10, one is a Core i7 with 16GB of ram, and another is another Core i7 with 32GB ram, all program files, project files and the SDKs are on nvme SSDs. Freeze is highly unlikely to be performance related.

Comment: anything peculiar in the IDE logs themselves? (as opposed to the console logs)

Comment: Where do I find the IDE logs?

Comment: (i'm on a Mac) "Help" -> "Show Log in Finder". naturally you'll have to do this while Studio is still responsive.

Comment: The studio is completely frozen, where does the IDE store it's logs.?

Comment: for me it's: `/Users/[USER-ID]/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio[VERSION]/idea.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further debugging, I found that is because of a problematic xml tool attribute with multiple recycler view that is causing the freeze in rendering, the code mistakened reference list item to itself

```
<!-- Layout file detail_content.xml -->
<!-- Recipe Ingredient List -->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/ingredient_list_rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:context="com.sample.app.StepListActivity"
    tools:listitem="@layout/detail_content"  <-- listItem references itself, casuing infinite loop />

<!-- Recipe Steps List -->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/step_list_rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:context="com.sample.app.StepListActivity"
    tools:listitem="@layout/detail_content" <-- listItem references itself, casuing infinite loop/>
```